# Two str_replace not working on same string

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm reading HTML file and I want to change all urls (in href and src attributes), for example, from this:

```
/static/directory/dynamic/directories
```

to this:

```
dynamic/directories
```

with this function:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        if(stripos($v, 'src=')!==false) {
            $array[$k] = str_replace('src="'.$this->getBadPathPart(), 'src="'.$d, $v);
        }
        if(stripos($v, 'href=')!==false) {
            $array[$k] = str_replace('href="'.$this->getBadPathPart(), 'href="'.$d, $v);
        }
    }
```

Everything works well except one situation: when there are two or more tags with src/href attribute in one line, only first gets changed. Why?

example:

> ... src="/bla/bla/test/test.png" .... href="/bla/bla/other" .... src="/bla/bla/doc.xls"

becomes:

> ... src="test/test.png .... href="/bla/bla/other" .... src="/bla/bla/doc.xls"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are modifying the value inside the array (`$array[$k]`) but then you continue making modifications using the stale value `$v` as a starting point instead of the value you have reached so far.

The clearest way to fix this is by looping with a reference:

```
foreach($array as &$v) {  // Note &$v
    if(stripos($v, 'src=')!==false) { 
        // You can now modify $v directly and the changes will
        // "stick" because you are looping by reference.
        $v = str_replace('src="'.$this->getBadPathPart(), 'src="'.$d, $v); 
    } 
    if(stripos($v, 'href=')!==false) { 
        $v = str_replace('href="'.$this->getBadPathPart(), 'href="'.$d, $v); 
    } 
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep your existing code but change every assignment to also update `$v`:

```
$array[$k] = $v = str_replace(...);
```